# MS SQL query to calculate link outage time and link up time

Tags: sql-server, networking, network-programming

Following table, top few lines for operational status of a device, every poll:

`samplevalue = 2` is operational status down, `samplevalue = 1` is operational status up

```
source          target                                              sampletime      samplevalue
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/2(Serial2/0/2)                                9/30/15 11:10   2
128.42.196.11   Fa3/0/0(FastEthernet3/0/0)                          9/30/15 11:10   1
128.42.196.11   Gi1/0/0.10(GigabitEthernet1/0/0.10)                 9/30/15 11:10   1
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/2.305(Serial2/0/2.305)                        9/30/15 11:10   2
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/2.309(Serial2/0/2.309)                        9/30/15 11:10   2
128.42.196.11   Gi1/0/0.20(GigabitEthernet1/0/0.20)                 9/30/15 11:10   1
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/2.300(Serial2/0/2.300)                        9/30/15 11:10   2
128.42.196.11   Gi0/0/0(GigabitEthernet0/0/0)                       9/30/15 11:10   1
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/2.306(Serial2/0/2.306)                        9/30/15 11:10   2
128.42.196.11   PO2/1/0(POS2/1/0--SONET/SDH Medium/Section/Line)    9/30/15 11:09   2
128.42.196.11   Tu10(Tunnel10-mpls layer)                           9/30/15 11:09   2
128.42.196.11   Tu4(Tunnel4)                                        9/30/15 11:09   2
128.42.196.11   Gi1/0/0.40(GigabitEthernet1/0/0.40)                 9/30/15 11:09   1
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/1(Serial2/0/1)                                9/30/15 11:09   1
128.42.196.11   Gi1/0/0.20(GigabitEthernet1/0/0.20)                 9/30/15 11:09   1
128.42.196.11   Tu10(Tunnel10)                                      9/30/15 11:08   2
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/0(Serial2/0/0)                                9/30/15 11:08   1
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/2.309(Serial2/0/2.309)                        9/30/15 11:08   2
128.42.196.11   Se2/0/2.306(Serial2/0/2.306)                        9/30/15 11:08   2
```

From above table we have to calculate how much time a particular interface of a device is with `sampletime = 1` and with `sampletime = 2` and that too only latest condition of interface.

I could able to work on following query:

```
with temp as ( 
    select 
        p.source, 
        p.target, 
        p.samplevalue,
        p.sampletime,
        lag(p.samplevalue,1) over (order by p.source, p.target, p.sampletime desc) as newvalue,
        lag(p.sampletime,1) over (order by p.source, p.target, p.sampletime desc) as changedat 
    from INTERFACE_OPERSTATUS p 
)
select * 
from( 
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by source, target order by source, target, changedat desc) as therow,
        source,
        target,
        samplevalue as oldvalue,
        newvalue,
        changedat,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,changedat,GETDATE()) as time
    FROM temp 
    where 
        newvalue <> samplevalue
        and newvalue = 2
) a 
where therow >= 1
```

Problem with above query is:

1. Even though link is up, it shows still in outage
2. Not able to consider latest link up condition
3. Need outage time between link down and link up (not able to consider link up)

Comment: what is the expected output from your sample?

Comment: What is an interface? Is it for example `Se2`, `Se2/0/2` or `Se2/0/2(Serial2/0/2)`?

Comment: Expected output: link which is up - total up time and link which is down - total down time. @JulienVavasseur

Comment: Yes, they are interfaces @DmitryPolyakov

Comment: @harikumarmunjala which one? :) If a whole string in `target` represents an interface, than no one interface from your sample change status.

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov - I have given only few lines, for every poll we get the oper status

Answer (score -1):

The following is tested against Oracle Database since I did not ready access to MS-SQL:

```
SELECT SOURCE, TARGET, SUM(UP_TIME) AS UP_TIME, SUM(DOWN_TIME) AS DOWN_TIME  FROM (
  SELECT LO.*, (SAMPLE_TIME - PREVIOUS_SAMPLE_TIME) * 24 * 60 AS  ACTUAL_TIME, 
     CASE SAMPLE_VALUE WHEN 1 THEN ((SAMPLE_TIME - PREVIOUS_SAMPLE_TIME) * 24 * 60) ELSE 0 END AS UP_TIME,
     CASE SAMPLE_VALUE WHEN 2 THEN ((SAMPLE_TIME - PREVIOUS_SAMPLE_TIME) * 24 * 60) ELSE 0 END AS DOWN_TIME
     FROM 
       (
         select SOURCE, TARGET, SAMPLE_VALUE, SAMPLE_TIME,  
         LAG(SAMPLE_TIME, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE,TARGET ORDER BY SOURCE, TARGET, SAMPLE_TIME) AS PREVIOUS_SAMPLE_TIME 
         from INTERFACE_OPERSTATUS
       ) LO
) GROUP BY SOURCE, TARGET ORDER BY SOURCE, TARGET;
```

The above query should work on MS-SQL as well with little syntax changes since I did not make use of Oracle only features.